# Include Curl in MFC project

Tags: c++, curl, mfc, unresolved-external, curlpp

I'm fairly new with curl. I need to use curl in c++ with the ssl support. 
I compiled OpenSSL with nmake and then, and I compiled libcurl as a static library with SLL SUPPORT via the VS10 project. The compilation worked and I tried to build a small console application example : That works !

But,  when I try to create an MFC project with these specific properties : 
MFC as a dialog box, without unicode, and using MFC in a static library. 
That doesn't work and I got the following unresolved symbols errors :

```
libcurl.lib(mprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp__fputc
1>libcurl.lib(tftp.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp__memchr
1>libcurl.lib(http.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp__memchr
1>libcurl.lib(userauth.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp__memchr
1>libcurl.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___fstat64
1>libcurl.lib(formdata.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___stat64
1>libcurl.lib(session.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___difftime64
1>libcurl.lib(kex.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___snprintf
1>libcurl.lib(knownhost.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___snprintf
1>libcurl.lib(scp.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___snprintf
1>libcurl.lib(misc.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___snprintf
1>libcurl.lib(transport.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu _imp___snprintf
1>libcurl.lib(channel.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___wassert
1>libcurl.lib(sftp.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___wassert
1>libcurl.lib(transport.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___wassert
1>libcurl.lib(userauth.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp__rewind
1>libcurl.lib(misc.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp__vsnprintf
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, curl compiles with the `/MD` (dll)  run-time library (that's why you get the `__imp__` prefix to the unresolved externals).

I assume you build your MFC project with `/MT` (statically linked run-time).

You can build curl with static run-time by setting the `RTLIBCFG` environment variable in your build console to `static`, like this:

`set RTLIBCFG=static`

Or just add manually `/MT` to the compiler flags and `/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT.lib` to the link flags in the makefiles, in case the first suggestion doesn't work.